# Pattern/Matcher group() to obtain substring in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, match

**UPDATE:** Thanks for all the great responses! I tried many different regex patterns but didn't understand why m.matches() was not doing what I think it should be doing. When I switched to **m.find()** instead, as well as adjusting the regex pattern, I was able to get somewhere.

---

I'd like to match a pattern in a Java string and then extract the portion matched using a regex (like Perl's $& operator).

This is my source string "s": `DTSTART;TZID=America/Mexico_City:20121125T153000`
I want to extract the portion "America/Mexico_City".

I thought I could use Pattern and Matcher and then extract using m.group() but it's not working as I expected. I've tried monkeying with different regex strings and the only thing that seems to hit on m.matches() is `".*TZID.*"` which is pointless as  it just returns the whole string. Could someone enlighten me?

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile ("TZID*:"); // <- change to "TZID=([^:]*):"
 Matcher m = p.matcher (s);
 if (m.matches ()) // <- change to m.find()
    Log.d (TAG, "looking at " + m.group ()); // <- change to m.group(1)
```

Comment: Looks like a line from an ics (iCal) file - why don't you use http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/ or equivalent?

Comment: Indeed. I started with ical4j but it hurled with an error when parsing the ics file so ditched it. I may try it again if I need more functionality than just extracting the DTSTART lines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use `m.match()` that tries to match the whole string, if you will use `m.find()`, it will search for the match inside, also I improved a bit your regexp to exclude TZID prefix using zero-width look behind:

```
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=TZID=)[^:]+"); //
     Matcher m = p.matcher ("DTSTART;TZID=America/Mexico_City:20121125T153000");
     if (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(m.group());
     }
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work nicely:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("TZID=(.*?):");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    String zone = m.group(1); // group count is 1-based
    . . .
}
```

An alternative regex is `"TZID=([^:]*)"`. I'm not sure which is faster.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a dot before the asterisk. Your expression will match any number of uppercase `D`s.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile ("TZID[^:]*:");
```

You should also add a *capturing group* unless you want to capture everything, including the `"TZID"` and the `":"`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile ("TZID=([^:]*):");
```

Finally, you should use the right API to search the string, rather than attempting to match the string in its entirety.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("TZID=([^:]*):");
Matcher m = p.matcher("DTSTART;TZID=America/Mexico_City:20121125T153000");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This [prints](http://ideone.com/ogwb5v)

```
America/Mexico_City
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong pattern, try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?TZID=([^:]+):.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher (s);
if (m.matches ())
    Log.d (TAG, "looking at " + m.group(1));
```

`.*?` will match anything in the beginning up to `TZID=`, then `TZID=` will match and a group will begin and match everything up to `:`, the group will close here and then `:` will match and `.*` will match the rest of the String, now you can get what you need in `group(1)`

Comment: I deleted my nearly identical answer in favor of yours.  You had a slightly better regex.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use split as:

```
  String origStr = "DTSTART;TZID=America/Mexico_City:20121125T153000";
  String str = origStr.split(":")[0].split("=")[1];
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thanks