# Find whether a string matches another string

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I'd like to parse a string in order to see if it matches the entire string or a substring.
I tried this:

```
String [] array = {"Example","hi","EXAMPLE","example","eXamPLe"};
String word;
...
if ( array[j].toUpperCase().contains(word) ||  array[j].toLowerCase().contains(word)  )
System.out.print(word + " ");
```

But my problem is:

When user enter the word `"Example"` (case sensitive) and in my array there is `"Example"` it doesn't print it, it only prints `"EXAMPLE"` and `"example"` that's because when my program compares the two strings it converts my `array[j]` string to uppercase or lowercase so it won't match words with both upper and lower cases like the word "Example".

So in this case if user enters `"Examp"` I want it to print:

```
Example EXAMPLE example eXamPLe
```

Comment: Program for... college exercise or something, or is this a real world application?

Comment: real world application for me

Comment: Define how is it a real world application. Or at least post that this is just an abstraction of the real code just to let us know the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert both the input string and the candidates to uppercase before calling contains().

```
if ( array[j].toUpperCase().contains( word.toUpperCase() ) ) {
    System.out.print(word + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking for full matches, use [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

<strike>When partial match is needed you might need a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or something similar.</strike>

Comment: Check the last case when input is `"Examp"`. By the way, no need to get too complicated with this. StringUtils from Apache Commons already handles this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks, living too long in the algorithm tag, knee-jerk reaction for me.

Comment: Using tries for this case is like using a guillotine to cut your hair :)

Answer (score 1):

Compare to the same case of `word`.

```
if ( array[j].toUpperCase().contains(word.toUpperCase()))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this:

```
if (array[j].toUpperCase().contains(word.toUpperCase())) {
    System.out.print(array[j]+ " ");
}
```

This will print:

```
Example EXAMPLE example eXamPLe
```

As you wanted!

Answer (score 0):

well, i think othehan using .equalsIgnoreCase u might also be interested in the Matcher( Java Regex). the links are self-explanaory: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html
[Pattern/Matcher group() to obtain substring in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767644/pattern-matcher-group-to-obtain-substring-in-java)
[String contains - ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018478/string-contains-ignore-case)

Answer (score 0):

Submit this as your assignment. You'll definitely come off as unique.

```
String word = "Exam";
String [] array = {"Example","hi","EXAMPLE","example","eXamPLe"};

for (String str : array)
  if (str.matches("(?i)"+word+".*"))
    System.out.print(str + " "); // prints: Example EXAMPLE example eXamPLe
```