# Java Pattern-match returning all group-Substrings

Tags: java, regex, match

I am looking for something very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767644/pattern-matcher-group-to-obtain-substring-in-java), only that I want all matches and not just the first one. In javascript, you can add a 'global' modifier in order to get a list of all matches, is something similar possible in java?

Comment: Since you do not provide a sample regex and input, it is unsure what you ask; anyway, note that a `Matcher` can match more than once; so, if you have instantiated a `Matcher`, you can do `while (m.find()) /* do something */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `while` instead of an `if` statement to iterate through the match results.

```
while (m.find()) {
  ...
}
```